# Unusual Response from neo4j query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have neo4j db with nodes like

```
(a : Project)-[:TAGGED]-(t : TAG)
(a : Project)<-[:HAVE_DONATED{amount, timestamp}]-(u : User)
```

I have 3 project in my db say a1, a2, a3 where a1, a2, a3 have 2, 3, 8 tags respectively. 2, 0 , 1 users have donated for a1, a2, a3 projects respectively. Now If I want to get total number of donation and donors for each project then  the result is depending upon tags. I don't know why.

```
Match (a : Project) 
Optional Match (a)-[r:HAVE_DONATED]-(u : User) 
return {id : a.id, donor : count(u), donation : sum(toInt(r.amount))} as project
```

1. id : a1,  donor:2, donation: 24667
2. id :a2, donor:0, donation:0
3. id : a3, donor : 1, donations:112000

which is correct and if I include tags then result is different.

```
Match (a : Project) 
Optional Match (a)-[:TAGGED]-(t :TAG)
, (a)-[r:HAVE_DONATED]-(u : User) 
return {id : a.id, donor : count(u), donation : sum(toInt(r.amount))} as project
```

1. id : a1,  donor:4, donation: 49334
2. id :a2, donor:0, donation:0
3. id : a3, donor : 8, donations:896000

   If i am including tags then donor and donations get multiplied by number of tags. Please help me where my query goes wrong.

Comment: Do you have some representative sample data you can provide?

Comment: @dave-bennett No, I don't have sample data.

Comment: @dave-bennett  I have written the queries on collabedit, please go through it. Due to some technical problem I an unable to share neo4j console link. Here is the link of collabedit. (http://collabedit.com/aywme). You just copy and paste the queries in your db and it will create all the necessary nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating a cartesian product by searching for the tags and the donations at the same time.  if you run this query I think you will see what is happening.

```
Match (a : Project) 
Optional Match (a)-[:TAGGED]-(t :TAG), (a)-[r:HAVE_DONATED]-(u : User) 
return a.id, u, r.amount
```

For each project, for every tag that is returned your donation is repeated.

I think what you may be after is something like this...

```
match (a : Project)
with a
optional Match (a)-[r:HAVE_DONATED]-(u : User)
with a, count(u) as donors, sum(r.amount) as donations
optional Match (a)-[:TAGGED]-(t :TAG)
with a, donors, donations, count(t) as tags
return {id : a.id, donor : donors, donation : donations, tag: tags} as project
```